# Best Practices to move metadata from sandbox to free developer org

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, migration

I need to move the metadata from sandbox to free developer org.I have 7 custom objects,pages,classes,components,static resources,updates to standard objects..Please suggest the best practices and order of items to push from sandbox to free developer org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Eclipse plugin](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) for that. Using Eclipse, select the metadata you want to deploy from the sandbox and then deploy to the dev org.

Another option is the [Ant Force.com migration tool](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/), but you'd need to get a package.xml with all the components in it for you to do that. The easiest way to get a package.xml is using Eclipse.

With either method you choose, you should be able to deploy everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

If You know what components to get, it is always easy using eclipse, as you can go to PROJECT ---> PROPERTIES ---> FORCE.COM --> PROJECT CONTENTS ---> ADD/REMOVE --> ADD all your components after it fetches the component metadata.